# Does Facebook block IFTTT backup recipes?

Tags: facebook, evernote, if-this-then-that

I've started using [this IFTTT recipe](http://ifttt.com/myrecipes/personal/1344942) to automatically backup all Facebook status updates / posts to Evernote (so I can finally [make them searchable](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-1/How-do-you-search-your-own-timeline-on-Facebook-If-we-cant-why-is-that)). However, it doesn't seem to do anything - no statuses are backed up at all.

The recipe log says "Trigger Timeout Error":

[image: Activity log]

Could Facebook be blocking this recipe?

Should I open a support ticket with IFTTT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a problem once with an IFTTT task and I wrote to them. It was fixed within a day.
So why don't you drop a mail to `support@ifttt.com` with your recipe ID and see what they have to say about this.

Comment: For the record, here is their reply ... I tried it, and it works: `Keep in mind that the NEW STATUS MESSAGE trigger for your Recipes will only work for STATUS MESSAGES (without links) and not LINK POSTS. Facebook sees these two types of posts as separate in its API, so IFTTT isn't able to group them together with that one Trigger.....yet!

Could this be why it isn't posting? We hope to include a general ANY NEW POST Trigger for the Facebook channel soon. In the meantime, create a new Recipe that uses the NEW LINK POST Trigger instead.`

Comment: I have the same issue and emailed back and forth with IFTTT. Triggers are set up correctly, activity log is showing it's working, recipe has been checked and it's still not working from facebook to Tumblr. I have even deleted the recipes and started again. No luck, any suggestions.
PS IFTTT have been patient but have now given up and blamed Tumblr, Tumblr blame Facebook...